# config.codekit reverts JS files with output/compilation unchecked

Tags: javascript, compilation, settings, config, codekit

Codekit only allows you to disable compilation of JS files on a per-file basis, but what's worse is it consistently reverts JS files I've already marked as no "compilation/output".

It happens when you open a JS file to edit it, or when you switch Git branches. You don't notice the change, Codekit does a background "refresh", and automatically updates your config.codekit. Next thing you know, you're saving the file, and Codekit is compiling a JS file you don't want.

I can work around by reverting changes to config.codekit, but in a large JS app, this is at best a poor workaround, and sitewide disabling of JS compilation should be an option.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone passes by this question and still needs help, I will give some answers I found which solved the problem for me.

First, you can edit file-processing settings project-wide. In the project settings, it is possible to apply an output parameter to all existing files with the "Apply" button:
[image]

---

Then, you have an option to pause file-watching with a simple shortcut that works across the whole system. It is useful to avoid unwanted changed made to CodeKit's config file when switching branch in Git.
You can find more details about it in the [CodeKit online documentation](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#critical-things):

> **Using CodeKit With Git or Subversion**
>   Before you perform any action that will change large numbers of files at once (switching branches, rebasing, pull requests, etc.) you MUST tell CodeKit to ignore file changes.

Comment: I have encountered this problem countless times, and I will continue to.  I can never remember to pause codekit's file monitoring!!